# Upload to azure blob storage - this.blobStorage.createBlobServiceWithSas is not a function

Tags: angular, azure-blob-storage, angular7

I have been following [this article](https://medium.com/@stuarttottle/upload-to-azure-blob-storage-with-angular-7977e979496a) to allow me to upload file directly to azure blob storage. But I currently get the error

> "this.blobStorage.createBlobServiceWithSas is not a function"

After confirming that I hadn't missed an instruction I looked at the source code in for the tutorial in [GitHub](https://github.com/stottle-uk/stottle-angular-blob-storage-upload), I saw a difference

**AppModule.ts in tutorial**

```
declare var AzureStorage: IAzureStorage;

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  providers: [
    BlobStorageService,
    {
      provide: BLOB_STORAGE_TOKEN,
      useValue: AzureStorage.Blob
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**AppModule in GitHub**

```
export function azureBlobStorageFactory(): IBlobStorage {
  return window['AzureStorage'].Blob;
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  providers: [
    BlobStorageService,
    {
      provide: BLOB_STORAGE_TOKEN,
      useFactory: azureBlobStorageFactory
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I updated my code accordingly but still no luck.

I then added a breakpoint to stop execution prior to `this.blobStorage     .createBlobServiceWithSas` being called. At this point I run `window['AzureStorage']` in the console and that returns undefined.

Can someone please advise me on what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

In angular.json I have added the required file. So if I run `window['AzureStorage'].Blob` in the console I get an object I can use, but i still get the same error as earlier in my code base

```
{
  ...
  "projects": {
    "Client": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            ...
            "scripts": [
              "src/assets/azure-storage/azure-storage.blob.js"
            ]
          },
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first issue was that I hadn't updated `angular.json` to include the `azure-storage.blob.js` script (I updated this in the question after making that change). I also needed to change how app.module.ts populated the service as below:

**from this**

```
export function azureBlobStorageFactory(): IBlobStorage {
  return window['AzureStorage'].Blob;
}

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    AzureBlobStorageService,
    {
      provide: BLOB_STORAGE_TOKEN,
      useValue: azureBlobStorageFactory()
    }
  ...
```

**to this**

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    AzureBlobStorageService,
    {
      provide: BLOB_STORAGE_TOKEN,
      useValue: window['AzureStorage'].Blob
    }
  ...
```